# Is it possible to load a non-AutoML trained tflite model for use with FirebaseAutoMLLocalModel on Android?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-automl, tensorflow-lite

It works well if I download the model from Firebase but it doesn't work if I try to replace the model with a manually trained model in TF which was then converted to tf-lite.

Do you think it's a limitation of AutoML or just something I missed in the conversion process?

Here is the error message:

```
2020-05-13 12:06:42.189 10296-10368/com.google.firebase.samples.apps.mlkit E/ODAutoMLImgLabelerTask: Error while loading the AutoML image labeling model.
    android.os.RemoteException
        at com.google.firebase.ml.vision.automl.zzj.zzol(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-automl@@18.0.5:89)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzso.zzol(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision@@24.0.3:78)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzqr.zzf(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-common@@22.1.1:53)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzqr$zza.zzoo(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-common@@22.1.1:7)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzqr$zza.call(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-common@@22.1.1:24)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzpx.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-common@@22.1.1:32)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzpw.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-common@@22.1.1)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zze.dispatchMessage(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-common@@22.1.1:6)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
     Caused by: com.google.firebase.ml.common.FirebaseMLException: Local model load failed with the model options: Local model path: automl/manifest.json. Remote model name: unspecified. 
        at com.google.firebase.ml.common.internal.modeldownload.zzj.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-common@@22.1.1:36)
        at com.google.firebase.ml.vision.automl.zzj.zzol(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-automl@@18.0.5:85)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzso.zzol(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision@@24.0.3:78) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzqr.zzf(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-common@@22.1.1:53) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzqr$zza.zzoo(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-common@@22.1.1:7) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzqr$zza.call(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-common@@22.1.1:24) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzpx.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-common@@22.1.1:32) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzpw.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-common@@22.1.1) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zze.dispatchMessage(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-common@@22.1.1:6) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61) 
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Internal error: Cannot create interpreter: Didn't find op for builtin opcode 'MUL' version '2'
    Registration failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Think it is a problem in the conversion/implementation in Android Studio.
I got the same problem but could not solve it.

I tested it with a .tflite from teachable machine and there were no problem...